# Create a POST arbitrary path route with Flask Python

Tags: python, api, rest, http, flask

I want to create a Flask route which captures an arbitrary path, and what I have done so far is this

```py
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_dir(path):
    req = request.json
    res = jsonify(req)
    res.status_code = 200

    return res
```

This code actually works pretty well, but every call is a GET call. What if I want to capture a POST call?

Comment: you need to add `methods=['POST']` in your @app.route

Comment: Yes of course, it was so simple ahaha Thank you!